# Wakaita -Tsurumi implementation in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

Does anyone know whether I can find communities of `Wakaita - Tusrumi` algorithm using `igraph`?

In the R-bloggers(https://www.r-bloggers.com/summary-of-community-detection-algorithms-in-igraph-0-6/) I found the above algorithm under `fast-greedy`, but what I understood is fastgreedy is for the community detection algorithm by Clauset, Moore, Newman based on modularity.

Comment: according to the igraph manual: http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Community.html#igraph_community_fastgreedy the fast-greedy community detection is Wakaita-Tsurumi which is an improvement on the algorithm by Clauset, Moore, Newman